# Google Ad Manager COLUMNS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REQUESTED_DIMENSION ReportError

Tags: report, line, items, google-ad-manager

I am trying to fetch report of **line items** and works fine from the UI but  halt with error via the API. Following is the reportQuery:

```
{'reportQuery': {
'dimensions': [
    'DATE',
    'LINE_ITEM_NAME',
    'LINE_ITEM_TYPE',
    'CREATIVE_SIZE_DELIVERED'
],
'adUnitView': 'TOP_LEVEL',
'columns': [
    'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS',
    'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CLICKS',
    'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_ALL_REVENUE'
],
'dimensionAttributes': [
    'LINE_ITEM_FREQUENCY_CAP',
    'LINE_ITEM_START_DATE_TIME',
    'LINE_ITEM_END_DATE_TIME',
    'LINE_ITEM_COST_TYPE',
    'LINE_ITEM_COST_PER_UNIT',
    'LINE_ITEM_SPONSORSHIP_GOAL_PERCENTAGE',
    'LINE_ITEM_LIFETIME_IMPRESSIONS'
],
'customFieldIds': [],
'contentMetadataKeyHierarchyCustomTargetingKeyIds': [],
'startDate': {
    'year': 2018,
    'month': 1,
    'day': 1
},
'endDate': {
    'year': 2018,
    'month': 1,
    'day': 2
},
'dateRangeType': 'CUSTOM_DATE',
'statement': None,
'includeZeroSalesRows': False,
'adxReportCurrency': None,
'timeZoneType': 'PUBLISHER'
}}
```

The above query throws following error when tried with API.

```
Error summary: {'faultMessage': "[ReportError.COLUMNS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REQUESTED_DIMENSIONS @ columns; trigger:'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_ALL_REVENUE']", 'requestId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'responseTime': '98', 'serviceName': 'ReportService', 'methodName': 'runReportJob'}
[ReportError.COLUMNS_NOT_SUPPORTED_FOR_REQUESTED_DIMENSIONS @ columns; trigger:'TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_ALL_REVENUE']
400 Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got identifier "TOTAL_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_ALL_REVENUE" at [1:354]
```

Did I miss anything? Any idea in this issue?
Thanks !

Comment: Make sure to be using the latest API version (at this moment :v201911) as the errors thrown in previous are as useful as the documentation of each Google product. In some cases a request made with `end_date` greater than today's date throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved by adding a dimension "Native ad format name".